# UIView's cornerRadius does not affect view evenly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, quartz-core

I am applying `cornerRadius` normally to a custom view as such:

`self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2`

However, I noticed that the resultant corner on the `UIView` is not evenly applied. Specifically, as seen in the attached photo, the top starts the fade into the corner earlier than the bottom part. While this is zoomed in, the uneven cornering is visible even at normal viewing level.
[image]

Has anyone also encountered this issue was able to resolve it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when does such a detailed inspection arise?

Comment: What is the height of your view?

Comment: you may be trying this code `self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2`  in  `viewDidLoad`  put this in   `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @Dhiru Good suggestion. For a tableViewCell (where this is found), I called `cell.didLayoutSubviews()` at the very end but the issue persisted.

Comment: @CoolPenguin the height is 20 points.

Comment: @daspianist : You can do in the `drawRect` method of you custom class of `UITableViewCell` this will work fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call this line?

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
```

This bug usually happens if cornerRadius is not half of FINAL size. 
e.g: you set this in viewDidLoad, the height of self is 100, the cornerRadius is now 50, but after self finished layout, its height become 90, the cornerRadius is still 50.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. If you use fixed constraint for height, you can set cornerRadius anywhere you want: self.layer.cornerRadius = self.someHeightConstraint.constraint / 2
2. If you don't, set cornerRadius after the view finishes layout (in its superview's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`)

Comment: This seemed like a possible cause to the issue as well, so I 1. set cornerRadius to a fixed number and 2. call layoutSubviews. However, the issue persists. Would be happy to paste more code. The view hierarchy is: 1. `tableViewCell.containerView` -> 2. `foregroundView` -> 3. `graphicView` The issue is at `graphicView`